# What do [in] and [out] mean in MSDN method documention?

Tags: .net, msdn

In http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms164519(v=vs.100).aspx, there is

```
HRESULT VirtualProtect (
    [in]  void*   lpAddress,
    [in]  SIZE_T  dwSize,
    [in]  DWORD   flNewProtect,
    [out] DWORD*  pflOldProtect
);
```

What do the [in] and [out] mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's showing which parameters are "inputs" and which are "outputs".  In this case, the address, size, and newProtect flags are all read in, and `pflOldProtect` is written to as an output.

Answer (score 0):

`[in]` means that the parameter is used by the function; `[out]` means that the parameter is returned by the function.